# Error when using passwd command - Syntax error

Tags: aix, passwd

I have an IBM AIX server, version 5.3

When attemping to change my password I get the following output:

```
(janthony)/home/janthony# passwd
passwd: root::  not found.
passwd[2]: password:  not found.
passwd[3]: lastupdate:  not found.
passwd[4]: flags:  not found.
passwd[6]: daemon::  not found.
passwd[7]: password:  not found.
passwd[9]: bin::  not found.
passwd[10]: password:  not found.
passwd[12]: sys::  not found.
passwd[13]: password:  not found.
passwd[15]: adm::  not found.
.
.
.
passwd[305]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 305 : `'' is not matched.
```

I have also tried issuing the command as root, but the result is the same.

I tried opening /etc/passwd to check line 305:

```
<username>:!:1037:1::/home/<username>:/usr/bin/ksh
```

I didn't see anything wrong with this line, so I ran a check to see if maybe a ' was placed somewhere in /etc/passwd by mistake, but the search came up empty.

Any ideas on what is going on here, or where I can check next to find the issue? Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT1: More info

```
(janthony)/# whoami
root
(janthony)/# echo $PATH
/coins/spool:/progress/oe102b:/progress/oe102b/bin:/coins:/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/home/janthony/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:.
(janthony)/# ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     system        16311 Nov 23 12:30 /etc/passwd
(janthony)/# type passwd
passwd is /coins/passwd
(janthony)/#
```

Comment: On AIX the `passwd` command is a shell script. The line error refers to this script. You should check your environment.

Comment: Have you tried `passwd root`? A bit of a long shot based on your output  but easy to try.

Comment: `pssswd` command is `/coins/passwd` and not `/usr/bin/passwd`??? What is supposed to be in that `/coins` directory? Why is it first in your PATH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a different `passwd` program early in your path -- apparently for a COINS program. The easiest workaround may be to use the full path to the OS passwd command: `/usr/bin/passwd`.